# Ionic 3, mouse click is triggered multiple times - FIXED

Tags: ionic-framework

I noticed strange behaviour in Ionic 3 while testing project in chrome browser (problem exist also on android as well).

When I start app and switch from main page to any other page, it works fine. 
However once I go back to main page and switch to other page, all mouse clicks are triggered multiple times.

Do you know the reason?

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.1  ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.1 
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Hi guys, sorry for bothering. However, posting helped me to understand the reason.
I thought that once event is subscribed in constructor, previous events are unsubscribed already, but it is not. 
Then, I was passing arrow function to unsubscribe as well, whether in this case second argument should be just empty (unsubscribe for all handlers).
This issue is closed.

Comment: never seen such issue. Can you please share some code?

Comment: It can be connected with how you attach input events in your components. Like if you do that in life cycle hooks that get used multiple times (ionViewDidEnter etc). Please share some code if you can otherwise its gonna be hard to help you.